# How can I detect url's in text and replace all _ with &lowbar; with a regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In our PHP project, we are using a library for Markdown that uses rules like `'/(\_)(.*?)\1/' => '<em>\2</em>'` for basic MD support.
Later those rules get executed with `$text = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text);`.

The problem is with url's, [https://example.com?_param=*value*](https://example.com?_param=_value_) would transform to  `https://example.com?_param=_value_` https://example.com?param=value (*** makes it italic).

So I'm trying to add a rule that detects url's and replaces all the underscores to _ in them.

```php
    public static $rules = array(
        '/(https?:\/\/)([^_ \n\r\t]*)(_)/' => '\1\2&lowbar;',
        '/(\_)(.*?)\1/' => '<em>\2</em>',
    );

    public static function render($text)
    {
        $text = "\n" . str_replace('<br>', "\n", $text) . "\n";
        foreach (self::$rules as $regex => $replacement) {
            if (is_callable($replacement)) {
                $text = preg_replace_callback($regex, $replacement, $text);
            } else {
                $text = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text);
            }
        }
        return trim($text);
    }
```

- Regex `(https?:\/\/)([^_ \n\r\t]*)(_)` only replaces the first match.
- Text: `_italic_ https://example.com?_param=_value_ _italic_`
- Expected: `_italic_ https://example.com?&lowbar;param=&lowbar;value&lowbar; _italic_`
- Actual: `_italic_ https://example.com?&lowbar;param=_value_ _italic_`

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
$str = '_italic_ https://example.com?_param=_value_ _italic_';
echo preg_replace('~(\G(?!^)|https?://)([^\s_]*)_~', '$1$2&lowbar;', $str);
```

Or

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|https?://)[^\s_]*\K_~', '&lowbar;', $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/iYRb3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgcJec/1/).

Alternatively, use `preg_replace_callback` with a simple two step approach (1 - get all substrings from `http://` or `https://` up to the first whitespace or end of string and 2 - replace all `_` inside the matches with your required value):

```
preg_replace_callback('~https?://\S+~', function($m) {
    return str_replace('_', '&lowbar;', $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IGPES).

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|https?://)` - `https://` or `http://` or the end of the previous match
- `[^\s_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `_` - a `_` char.